# I am trying to use ensemble learner method sklearn but having model fit issue, getting an value error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, ensemble-learning

This is my code, I have those models 1 to 4 run in above cells without any errors.
I will also show my test train split.

[Train test split & smote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCDfM.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVjlA.png)

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier    
estimators=[('lr', model1,('RF1', model2), ('nn', model3),('RF2',model4))]
model5 = VotingClassifier(estimators, voting='hard')
model5.fit(X_train_nns,y_train_nns)
ypred_en=model5.predict(X_test)
model5.score(X_test, y_test)
```

This is how i split & over sampled it

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.10, 
random_state=42)
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE()
X_train_nns, y_train_nns = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: You'll need to clarify a bit. Which line in the corresponding code is the error being thrown on?

Comment: The model.fit() is raising error                                                                                   (i have uploaded the image in body).

Comment: Why did you use `.values` at `y_train` and not by `X_train`?

Comment: Before i used without values.ravel() but it gave me an error and suggested to use it.  When i used it for X-train i gave me an error saying expecting a 2d array instead of 1d array.

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted instead of images. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So, please give me a minimal sample of X_train and y_train because it seems to me, there is some problem at this point. Or it is better if you give a minimal sample of DataFrame, which you made them from.

Comment: my original data set has a target variable (classes) & 122 features. so my y-variable is a 1d array & my features are 2d array. will that be causing some issues.

Comment: Please, understand, that I'm trying to help you, but you have to provide some minimal original (or any fake, but same structured) data to be able to reproduce your issue and find the solution for it, because at the current state can be a lot of place where the problem can be rooted from.